# Change font style with CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-text

I have a regular font in a label called `_label` and I' trying to make it bold and then only italic (so I want to remove the bold style)

To make it bold, I'm using the following code :

```
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)_label.font.fontName, _label.font.pointSize, NULL);
CTFontRef boldFont = CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits(font, 0.0, NULL, kCTFontBoldTrait, kCTFontBoldTrait);
CFStringRef boldName = CTFontCopyFullName(boldFont);
_label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:(__bridge NSString *)boldName size:_label.font.pointSize];
```

This is working great. However when I'm trying to make it only italic, with the following code, the font ends up bold and italic:

```
font = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)_label.font.fontName, _label.font.pointSize, NULL);
boldFont = CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits(font, 0.0, NULL, kCTFontBoldTrait | kCTFontItalicTrait, kCTFontItalicTrait); // I also tried 'kCTFontItalicTrait, kCTFontItalicTrait' for the last two parameters
boldName = CTFontCopyFullName(boldFont);
_label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:(__bridge NSString *)boldName size:_label.font.pointSize];
```

Obviously I'm not using CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits correctly. How to remove the bold style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
boldFont = CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits(font, 0.0, NULL, kCTFontItalicTrait, kCTFontBoldTrait | kCTFontItalicTrait);
```

(although you might want to change your variable name).

The `symTraitMask` parameter (the last one) indicates which bits of the trait mask should be affected by the call. You want to affect both the "bold" and "italic" bits.

The `symTraitValue` parameter (second to last) indicates the new values for the affected bits. You want those bits to be changed to have "italic" but not have "bold".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know anything about performances of these operations compared to creating a new font with UIFont fontWithName: ?

Comment: You're welcome. No, I'm afraid I don't know anything about that.

Comment: After few tests, it looks like + (UIFont *)fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:(CGFloat)fontSize is ~40 times faster than the CoreText technique used in this post

Comment: Well, the technique *uses* `+[UIFont fontWithName:size:]` so it couldn't conceivably be faster than it. Certainly it has some overhead. Why is the speed important? Are you creating fonts (and bold or italic variants) with such frequency that it matters? Why don't you just create the fonts once and keep them for as long as they are needed?